# Spring 4 / ExtJs 6 File Upload - ExtJs connection refused error when file size limit exceed

Tags: javascript, spring, extjs, spring-security, extjs6

I have a file upload form that's working correctly except when I send a file that is larger than the size that I've configured in Spring.

I've used the same code before on another application that was written in Spring, the difference is I was using ExtJs 4.2, now using ExtJs 6.0. As well the old app used Spring security 3, the new one 4.

The Spring side has been configured to block files that exceed 3MB.

From WebMvcConfig.java:

```
@Bean(name="multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver commonsMultipartResolver() 
{
    ToolkitCommonsMultipartResolver resolver = new ToolkitCommonsMultipartResolver();
    resolver.setMaxUploadSize(Constants.UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE);
    return resolver;
}
```

From ToolkitCommonsMultipartResolver:

```
public class ToolkitCommonsMultipartResolver extends CommonsMultipartResolver {

@SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
@Override
protected MultipartParsingResult parseRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {

    String encoding = determineEncoding(request);
    FileUpload fileUpload = prepareFileUpload(encoding);

    List fileItems;

    try {
        fileItems = ((ServletFileUpload) fileUpload).parseRequest(request);
    } 
    catch (FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException ex) {
        System.out.println("******* MultipartParsingResult limit exceeded");
        request.setAttribute("fileSizeExceeded", ex);
        fileItems = Collections.EMPTY_LIST;            
    } 
    catch (FileUploadException ex) {
        throw new MultipartException("Could not parse multipart servlet request", ex);
    }

    return parseFileItems(fileItems, encoding);
}
```

}

My custom Controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ACTIVITY_CREATE_UPDATE')")
@RequestMapping(value = "/activity/editActivity", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes="multipart/form-data", produces=MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE )
public @ResponseBody String editActivity(@Valid ActivityBean bean, BindingResult result, HttpServletRequest request) {

    //WebMvcConfig.commonsMultipartResolver will throw exception if file size exceeds the max size
    //Passed as a request attribute
    Object exception = request.getAttribute("fileSizeExceeded");
    if (exception != null && FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException.class.equals(exception.getClass())) 
    {
        log.info("File too large");
        String msg = "The file you sent has exceeded the maximum upload size of " + (Constants.UPLOAD_MAX_FILE_SIZE / 1000000L) + " MB.";
        return "{\"success\" : false, \"msg\" : \"" + msg + "\"}";
    }

    ...other code to process request
}
```

}

Spring security http tag has the following code to allow frame content to be displayed from the server (X-Frame-Options). Before I added this code all the responses were blocked (save was successful or not):

```
<headers>
    <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN"/>
</headers>
```

Spring will return success: false with the message I've setup in the controller. In chrome, I see connection aborted (net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED). Deep in ExtJs code I found the method onComplete:

```
/**
 * Callback handler for the upload function. After we've submitted the form via the
 * iframe this creates a bogus response object to simulate an XHR and populates its
 * responseText from the now-loaded iframe's document body (or a textarea inside the
 * body). We then clean up by removing the iframe.
 * @private
 */
onComplete: function()
```

Inside onComplete() there is a call after the upload

```
doc = me.getDoc();
```

This method tries to access the content returned from the server in the iFrame is blocked. It seems as though the Spring security header isn't working in this case. There is a catch (e) that is throwing the error:

Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:8080" from accessing a cross-origin frame.(…)

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue? I can disable the Muitipart resolver and accept the complete file, and do size validation in my custom code. It makes more sense to block the file upload first if it exceeds the size. Is this a Spring security 4 or ExtJs6 issue?

Comment: 'except when I send a file that is larger than the size that I've configured in Spring' . What do you expect Spring to do then?

Comment: The multipart resolver cuts off the request and should return a message to the client telling them the file is too large.

Comment: Then in you catch block, you can process the catch block instead of throwing exception.

Comment: The exception must be thrown, it's the only way to identify there was a problem when the controller runs later. I catch it as a FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException and handle it there. This doesn't have anything to do with the issue.